# SQL Server 2014 Concurrent input issue

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, unique-constraint

In table `Orders`, I store the orders we receive from all shops. Since an order can have multiple lines, among the columns there are `OrderID` and `OrderLineID`
where `OrderID` can be duplicated but `OrderLineID` has to be unique within an order.

Since orders can be amended, the stored procedure first checks if the received order's `OrderLineID` is already present in the table, and then decides to insert or to update. To do this we:

- build the insert and update statements dynamically from the XML input
- insert into customers table
- insert into shippingAddresses table

and then the main table:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from Orders where OrderLineID=@OrderLineID ......)
INSERT INTO Orders () VALUES ()
ELSE UPDATE Orders SET ... WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID
```

Or does the `MERGE` function offer better performances/control?

But the question is the following:

Due to line issue/server busy and so on, the `Order` message (or the modification), could be sent more than once, and we do not know in which sequence. Therefore, to avoid the `Order` arriving after the amendment, and therefore overwriting the amendment, we added a time column:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from Orders where OrderLineID=@OrderLineID)
INSERT INTO Orders () VALUES ()
ELSE UPDATE Orders SET ... WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID AND LastModified<@CreatedTime
```

In this way if the later message is older than the previous, it has no effect on the table.

But, it could happen that the message and its modification are sent twice (or more) in so little timeframe that the latter message arrives before the former has been saved. Therefore the `IF NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from Orders where OrderLineID=@OrderLineID)` is **TRUE** for both executions of the stored procedure, and both times it generates an `INSERT` and we find duplicated rows.

Perhaps this can be avoided by simply setting `OrderLineID` as **unique key**?

I also read something about using:

```
set transaction isolation level serializable
```

but I'm not sure how this is handled. I not only want to **avoid the duplicate rows** but to be sure the later message executes the `UPDATE` query and not throw a *unique key violation*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

`MERGE` has some issues you should be aware of, see [Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) by Aaron Bertrand.

More specifically to your present situation, `MERGE` provides no additional protection against concurrency issues beyond an automatic containing transaction. You would need to add a `SERIALIZABLE` hint (or its synonym, `HOLDLOCK`) to the `MERGE` statement as well, see [“UPSERT” Race Condition With MERGE](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx) by Dan Guzman. Note that an `UPDLOCK` hint is not necessary with `MERGE`.

For a more general overview of the issues and options, see the following by Michael J. Swart:

- [SQL Server UPSERT Patterns and Antipatterns](http://michaeljswart.com/2017/07/sql-server-upsert-patterns-and-antipatterns/)
- [Mythbusting: Concurrent Update/Insert Solutions](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/)

A popular and robust solution is to add a `WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)` hint to table access in the `NOT EXISTS` check, with a containing transaction around the whole `UPSERT` operation.

Using your example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID
)
    INSERT INTO Orders () VALUES ()
ELSE
    UPDATE Orders 
    SET ... 
    WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID 
    AND LastModified<@CreatedTime;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Or equally:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO Orders ()
SELECT ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM Orders WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID
);

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE Orders 
    SET ... 
    WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID 
    AND LastModified<@CreatedTime;
END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The order of the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations can be switched so that whichever you expect to succeed most often is tried first. The hints must always be applied to the first operation.

For example, if updates are expected to be most numerous:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE Orders WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
SET ... 
WHERE OrderLineID=@OrderLineID 
AND LastModified<@CreatedTime;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Orders ()
    SELECT ...
END;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The uniqueness constraint mentioned in the question is a good idea for consistency in general, but not strictly needed for the methods noted here. If you were to use Michael Swart's *Just Do It* pattern, a uniqueness guarantee would be required for correct operation.

As a reminder, if you prefer `MERGE` for whatever reason, you must use a `SERIALIZABLE` hint against the target table.

While it is true in general that locking hints should be avoided as far as possible, this is one example of a valid use case.

Answer (score -2):

The serializable transaction guarantees that all your transactions that are running concurrently will make the same effect as they run one after another.

This means that if you have 2 transactions that wants to query the same rows in the same table, the one which starts later will wait until the first one commit/roolback.

For example we have 2 rows in table orderLabel where orderID = 1

12:00 Serializable Transaction 1 starts with query - `select count(*) from orderLable where orderID = 1`

12:01 Serializable Transaction 2 starts with query - `insert into orderLabel(orderID) values(1) -- this will wait until Transaction 1 commit/roolback`

12:02 T1 commits and returs 2

12:03 T2 inserts 1 row with orderID = 1 and commits.

In your case Serializable will do the work, because when it it reaches the line `IF NOT EXISTS(Select 1 from Orders where OrderLineID=@OrderLineID ......)`
It will put lock on that rows and no other transaction will be able to insert data with the same @orderLineID.

Comment: ... OR fail with a deadlock.  Here both sessions would take Shared Key Range locks on OrderTable, and then deadlock when attempting to update.  The SERIALIZABLE isolation level is 80% useless, and 19% harmful.